How to fix empty Network Tab on flutter devtools?
Network tab on flutter devtools is always empty. It doesn't show any requests made by my app. I am running my app with command line:
flutter run --debug

Devtools are opened in terminal by pressing shortcut "v".
All other tabs in flutter devtools are working correctly except "most needed" network tab.
Application is run in iOS simulator and android emulator.

